# Instance method at top level

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
module M
  def m
    "hello"
  end
end

include M

m # => hello
M.m # => hello
```

By including `M` at the top level, I can call `m`. How come I can call `M.m`?

Answer (score 4):

Invoking `include M` at the top level includes your module in `Object`:

```
module M
  def m
    "hello"
  end
end

include M

Object.included_modules #=> [M, Kernel]
```

You can achieve the same with:

```
class Object
  include M
end
```

And because everything in Ruby is an object, you can send `m` to every object<sup>1</sup>, including instances and classes and modules (like `M`):

```
123.m        #=> "hello"
'foo'.m      #=> "hello"
String.m     #=> "hello"
Object.m     #=> "hello"
Enumerable.m #=> "hello"
M.m          #=> "hello"
```

<sup>1</sup> *an object in the sense of `is_a? Object`*

Comment: Except, of course: `BasicObject.new.m # NoMethodError`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag is a `BasicObject` instance actually an object?

Comment: It has instance variables, it has a singleton class, it has a class, you can call methods on it, you can store it in a variable, you can pass it as an argument, you can return it from a method, there is no difference between an instance of `BasicObject`, an instance of `Object` or an instance of `String`, except for where its internal `class` pointer points to. So, yes, it is definitely an **object**, but not an `Object`. Within all of the Ruby implementations, there is no special representation for an instance of `BasicObject`, it's just an object like any other which has a class which just …

Comment: … happens to be a superclass of `Object` instead of a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The "default definee" (i.e. the module that methods defined with `def` and `include`d mixins end up in) at the top-level is `Object`.

This means that `M` gets included into `Object`, i.e. `M` becomes a superclass of `Object`, inserted underneath `Kernel`. Since `M` is an instance of module, and `Module` is a subclass of `Object` and `Object` now is a subclass of `M`, it is possible to call `M.m`.

The ancestry chain of `Module` is:

```
[Module, Object, M, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

ergo, `M` is in the method lookup path for `M`, and therefore `M.m` finds the method defined in `M`.

Answer (score 0):

Even more weird example:

```
▶ module M ; end
▶ def m ; puts '¡Hola!' ; end
#⇒ :m
▶ M.m
#⇒ ¡Hola!
```

So, let’s dig into object inheritance. The execution context is `main`. `main` is apparently a “special” instance of `Object`, propagating all the methods defined on it to be visible everywhere. Since `Module` instance (`M`) is in fact an instance of `Object`, it all of a sudden responds to each `Object` method. But we just have an `Object` extended with `m` method.

Note: `module M ; def m ; end ; end; include M` and `def m ; end` on a top level do almost the same thing: both extend `Object` with `m` method (the latter makes this method `private` on `Object`, though.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. One adds `m` to `Object`, the other mixes `M` into `Object`. Those are two completely different things. In particular, `def m` will make `m` a `private` instance method of `Object`, and thus `M.m` will `raise` a `NoMethoError`: `ruby -e 'module M; end; def m; end; M.m' # -e:1:in '<main>': private method 'm' called for M:Module (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for pointing out that methods defined on `main` become `private`. That funny fact still does not make mixing modules and defining methods on objects different things. _Mixing a module containing the only method to an object does by no means differ from declaring this method on an object directly_ (from a point of view of this object of course.) `main` weirdness is still `main`-specific.

Comment: The inheritance chain, thus the method lookup path, thus `super` is different, for example. The module could be mixed into more than one class (e.g. `BasicObject`).